# Performance testing result analysis using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I need to undergo performance testing for my project and I have learned how to Handle the Jmeter for Performance testing through online, but still, i was unable to find the solution how to analyze the result? from the report.I do know how to analyze the result so that I can't able to find the Performance Issue I n m application, where the error had been occurring, so from that how I can improve that performance.Is there is any article or video tutorial to learn how to analyze the result?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible test outcomes:

1. Positive: the performance of your application matches [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) and/or [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement). In this case you need to provide the report as a proof, it might be i.e. [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
2. Negative: the performance of your application is beyond the expectations. In this case you need to perform some investigation on the reasons, which could be in:

   - Simply lack of resources, i.e. your application doesn't have enough headroom to operate due to not enough CPU, RAM, Network or Disk bandwidth. So make sure you are monitoring these resources on the application under test side, you can do it using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).
   - The same but on JMeter load generator(s) side. If JMeter cannot send requests fast enough the application won't be able to serve more requests so if JMeter machine doesn't have enough resources - the situation will be the same so make sure to monitor the same metrics on JMeter host(s) as well
   - You have some software configuration problem (i.e. application server thread pool, db connection pool, memory settings, caching settings, etc. are not optimal). In the majority of cases web, application and database servers default configuration is not suitable for high loads and it needs to be tuned so try playing with different settings and see the impact.
   - Your application code is not optimal. In case when there is a plenty of free hardware resources and you are sure that infrastructure is properly set up (i.e. other applications behave fine) it might be a problem with your application under test code. In this case you will need to re-run your test with [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to see what are the most time and resources consuming methods and how they can be optimised.
   - It might also be a networking related problem, i.e. faulty router or bad cable or whatever.

There are too many possible reasons however the approach should be the same: the whole system acts at the speed of its slowest component so you need to identify this component and determine why it is slow. See [Understanding Your Reports](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-4-how-read-your-load-testing-reports-blazemeter) posts series to learn how to read JMeter load test results and identify the bottlenecks from them.